# Prevent past date selection

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I was wondering if it is possible to prevent the user from selecting a date in the past on the bootstrap datepicker?

I tried using `.datepicker({ preventPast: true })`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
.done(function (response) {
                        view.data = response;
                        $pageHeader.after(view.options.template(response));
                        view.$('.datepicker:not([readonly])')
                            .datepicker({ preventPast: true })
                            .on('changeDate', function () {
                                $(this).datepicker('hide');
                            });
```

Comment: Be sure to check it on the server-side too. _Just saying_

Comment: It would help if you could specify exactly *which* datepicker plugin you're using.  Looks like [eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/)?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `minDate` to prevent a date in the past from being chosen.

For example:

```
$('#datePickerId').datepicker({minDate: '0'});
```

Comment: Make sure that when you initialize your datepicker that you have made a new date object that is set as minDate.

Comment: I tried that too... but I can still select the previous dates.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI datepicker works for me without the quotes. `preventPast` isn't an option for [jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max), so mehtinks you're using a different plugin?

```
​$("#datePickerId")​​​​​​​​​​​​.datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

JS Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/7Uaew/

Also, +1 to sherbrow; don't forget the server validation.

Comment: I am not using the jQuery datepicker. As I mentioned in my post I am using the bootstrap datepicker that doesn't seem to like the minDate:0.

Comment: Whoops, I surely feel like an idiot. I have heard of that guy, but not used it. I was thrown by the 'jquery' tag you put on there. I'll try to figure out a real answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [startDate](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/#startdate): `.datepicker({ startDate: '+0d' });`

Comment: Tried that... but it still lets me pick the earlier dates.

Comment: Hm... are you using the latest code?  That feature may have been added since you last updated.  If you are, can you build a jsfiddle with the code you're using?